# How to Set Default Access for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is an easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

When I log into the command line mysql program, I want to have root access by just typing `mysql`. However, I need to type `mysql -uroot -p`, and then enter my password. How can I change this?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-log-on-to-mysql-automatically.html) is a tutorial on getting MySql to log you in automatically.

Just follow the steps and you should be able to login to MySql by simply typing `mysql`, as shown in the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you first install mysql, the furst thing you should do is give root@localhost a password. To set the password to `mys3cr3t`, run the following:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('mys3cr3t')
WHERE host='localhost' and user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT
```

Now, you have to login with `mysql -uroot -p`

Next, you need to cleanup all security hazards. There is a script called `mysql_secure_installation`. Run it ASAP. Here is what is does: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13350/877

If you do not, there is a possibility of a Disk Level database attack : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13363/877

To test to see whether you have proper user authentication, run this:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

What does this query tell you ???

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

[CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

If `CURRENT_USER()` reports any anonymous users, go run `mysql_secure_installation` now !!!